# Swift: temporarily storing image locally while app is in foreground and background

Tags: swift, image, background, local-storage, foreground

I am trying to store images locally while the user is running the app and also keep the images stored locally while the app is in the background. When the user terminates the app, then the data should disappear locally and only be loaded once the user reopens the app. I know how to load the images initially, but I am considering where/how to store the images locally.

I know that Swift has the file system, but I was wondering if this is the best practice for this kind of implementation or if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want is not possible, but you can do something similar in functionality.

To cache images you can simply use an existing library, like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage). It manages asynchronous image downloading and caching for you, and to clear cached images you can simply do

```
SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearMemory()
SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearDisk()
```

Now, as for **when** you want to clear the cache, it get's a little tricky.

You can't clear the cache when terminating the app, because there is no way to reliably detect when the app is terminated. There is `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationWillTerminate` method, but it is not called if the app is terminated while in suspended state.

But you can do a workaround: simply clear the cache upon launching the app in `UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, which will be functionally equivalent of what you want to do.